# Cannot submit the application form for requesting access to the Amazon advertising API

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

We wish to access the amazon advertising API and we follow the steps in this link to apply as a partner. However when we tried to submit an application we encountered an error that says,

> Please ensure that you are signed into the Amazon account affiliated
> with your corporate email address. If you do not have an Amazon
> account affiliated with your corporate email address, you may update
> your current Amazon account or create an account

We have tried various accounts and email addresses affiliated with Amazon but it still produces the same error. Also, I don't know what corporate email address are they referring to. I've also posted it on other forums since last week but didn't get any replies so I'm trying it here because maybe a user here knows how to resolve it. I've tried also the amazon advertising API customer support team but it seems that I need to have my application approved first before I can submit a ticket.
[image]

Comment: I just got the same problem. Were you able to resolve the error?